# In JSP, is there a way to see all available variables in the specific scope like in PHP?

Tags: jsp, jstl

Or better yet how do I dump all the variables in a given scope in jsp?

(In php you can use a function call to see all the system, global and user-defined vars and functions available...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30946&seqNum=7) for an overview of all objects that can be accessed, and a small piece of demo code demonstrating the access per object using the JSTL.